# How do I save and load all files in a sublime text session as a 'project'?

Tags: sublimetext

I've read that you can save a ' project ' but apparently I'm doing it wrong.

What I've done is...

Create a js, html and css file and use view/layout with 3 columns so
   each file has its own section of the layout.

I then went to **Project / save project as /**  and saved the respective file in
   a directory

I assumed that all files should be saved in this directory along with a file that I can click that loads them all up to reflect the workflow.
Apparently sublime has a different idea of how this should work and I do not understand it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essentially, there are two parts to a Sublime project - a `.sublime-project` file, and a `.sublime-workspace` file. Please see both the ["unofficial" docs](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/file_management/file_management.html#projects) and the [official website](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/projects.html) for information regarding projects, and the setup of `.sublime-project` files. These files are [JSON](http://json.org)-formatted and contain paths to any folders contained in your project, project-specific settings, and project-specific build systems. This file can (and should) be edited to customize the project to your needs. Double-clicking this file (after associating its file type with Sublime, following the procedure of your operating system) will open the project, any open files within it, and any folders you've added to it (by selecting **`Project -> Add Folder to Project`**).

The `.sublime-workspace` file is also JSON-formatted, but is saved automatically by Sublime and shouldn't be edited unless you ***really*** know what you're doing, and even then you probably shouldn't edit it. It contains all sorts of meta information about the project's history in Sublime, which files were open and in what order/pane, previous contents of searches, find/replace, etc., your file history, settings for various plugins like `SublimeCodeIntel`, and lots more. By default it is hidden when viewing the contents of folders in the Side Bar, and when double-clicked it will try to open the project instead of opening for viewing/editing, so there are several measures in place to prevent your playing with it and potentially screwing up Sublime.

`.sublime-project` files can be saved wherever you want, but the folders and files contained within it are not necessarily saved in the same place - they stay wherever they were saved. It usually makes sense to save them in the project's root directory, so if you have a filesystem like `myhomedir/projects/web/SweetWebsite/` containing `html/`, `js/`, and `css/` subdirectories, you might want to save your project as `.../SweetWebsite/SweetWebsite.sublime-project`, just so you know at a glance what files/folders are probably in it. However, you could save `SweetWebsite.sublime-project` in `myhomedir/Desktop` for all Sublime cares, and it would work exactly the same way. While it is possible to have unsaved files in a project, of course it's always best to save your work early and often, so you don't lose anything.

Hopefully this helps, please let me know if you have further questions.